# jasmine - how to check if an argument exists?

Tags: jasmine

good day.

im testing to see function got all her args.

i know what value two of her args must have,

but for the third arg, i just want to test if it exists.

```
expect(myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWithMatcher({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: dont know its val but want it to exist
});
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `jasmine.any`. In case you expect a number it could be:

```
expect(myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: jasmine.any(Number)
});
```

It is also possible `jasmine.any(Function)` and so on. From Jasmine doc:

> jasmine.any takes a constructor or “class” name as an expected value. It returns true if the constructor matches the constructor of the actual value.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
  expect(myFunction.mostRecentCall.args[2]).toBeDefined();
```

and leave out the argument in the toHaveBeenCalledWith test.

Comment: thanks very much :) p.s - sorry i didnt vote up - i need more rep to be able to ...

Comment: Are you sure with that? I think the function takes only one argument so with this approach it should be `expect(myFunction.mostRecentCall.args[0].c).toBeDefined()`.